# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named

Tags: python, python-import

gente!
Tengo el siguiente fallo en consola:

*Version 2.0\paqueteJugador\Jugador.py", line 2, in 
from Main import hecharJugador
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Main'*

Sé qué quiere decir y todo sobre la ortografía, está bien! Pero igual sale este error.
Ahora paso foto del directorio.
[image: Desde Jugador.py trato de hacer la importación]

[image: Acá está el Main.py]

Este es el extracto de código de mi importación

```
from Main import hecharJugador
```

Si alguien me puede ayudar, le agradezco mucho

Comment: Gracias Christian! No sabía como hacer eso

Comment: El archivo  `Main.py` esta en otro directorio (un nivel más arriba) eso también lo debes especificar al hacer el import

Comment: Ah! Genial! Y eso cómo lo debería hacer?

Comment: Me da este error: ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package.  Probé borrando el test.py, pero da lo mismo.

Comment: Debes plantear mejor la estructura de módulos. El mecanismo de importación no funciona así. Cuando se importa un módulo, se busca entre las rutas dadas por `sys.path`. Para `Main`, `paqueteJugador` está en su ruta de búsqueda de módulos, mientras que para `paqueteJugador`, el módulo `Main` no está accesible. Podrías añadir el directorio padre al `sys.path`, pero no es lo aconsejable.

Comment: Podría darte algún consejo más, pero no sé para qué quieres acceder a `Main` desde `paqueteJugador`. Cambia el código para que no tener estados globales (variables globales), que toda la información que necesite el paquete se la pase Main.

Comment: Si, @ChemaCortes mil gracias por tu ayuda, he estado leyendo sobre todas las importaciones y en python son un lío. Además, agregarlas al path no da, porque seguro quiero compartirlo. Así que empecé a cambiar el código. Igual hubiera estado lindo haberlo podido resolver y aprender cómo se hace, no solo tapar lo que no pude hacer. De todas formas les agradezco su ayuda

Comment: Aunque no lo parezca, la gestión de módulos y sus dependencias es tremendamente complicado, indepedientemente del lenguaje. Que dos módulos sean dependientes recíprocamente, uno del otro, es origen de tremendos problemas para algunas aplicaciones.

Comment: @ChemaCortes no lo sabía, muchísimas gracias nuevamente, siempre se puede aprender más.